# Pair rows in Pandas DataFrame if condition met

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame like following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 
    'amount':[100, -100, 50, 30, -30, 40]
})
```

If I would like to add another column as to check if the amount of each row can be paired (i.e. same amount, but 1 positive and 1 negative) within a group.

For example, in group A, 100 & -100 can be paired, then they will be True, while 50 cannot find a pair, then it's False (like the following table).

| group | amount | pair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | True |
| A | -100 | True |
| A | 50 | False |
| B | 30 | True |
| B | -30 | True |
| C | 40 | False |

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take the [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) of the `amount` column, then create the `pair` column based on where the values are [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['pair'] = df.assign(amount=df['amount'].abs()).duplicated(keep=False)
```

*`keep=False` means both duplicated rows get `True`. The right hand side can also be `subset` if the DataFrame has more than these 2 columns.

`df`:

```
  group  amount   pair
0     A     100   True
1     A    -100   True
2     A      50  False
3     B      30   True
4     B     -30   True
5     C      40  False
```

---

Update to handle duplicate values, but ensure only positive negative pairs get matched using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

Updated DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'amount': [100, -100, 50, 50, 30, -30, 40]
})
```

Pivot to wide form and check for pairs:

```
df['abs_amount'] = df['amount'].abs()
df = df.join(
    df.pivot_table(index=['group', 'abs_amount'],
                   columns=df['amount'].gt(0),
                   values='amount',
                   aggfunc='first')
        .notnull().all(axis=1)
        .rename('pair'),
    on=['group', 'abs_amount']
).drop('abs_amount', axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
  group  amount   pair
0     A     100   True
1     A    -100   True
2     A      50  False
3     A      50  False
4     B      30   True
5     B     -30   True
6     C      40  False
```

---

The `pivot_table`:

```
df['abs_amount'] = df['amount'].abs()
df.pivot_table(index=['group', 'abs_amount'],
               columns=df['amount'].gt(0),
               values='amount',
               aggfunc='first')
```

```
amount            False   True
group abs_amount              
A     50            NaN   50.0  # Multiple 50s but no -50
      100        -100.0  100.0
B     30          -30.0   30.0
C     40            NaN   40.0
```

Ensure all values in the row:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['group', 'abs_amount'],
               columns=df['amount'].gt(0),
               values='amount',
               aggfunc='first').notnull().all(axis=1)
```

```
group  abs_amount
A      50            False
       100            True
B      30             True
C      40            False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Small improvement df.assign(pair = df['amount'].abs().duplicated(keep=False))

Comment: But what if C had amount 100? Then C (idx 5) `pair` would be would be marked `True` even though there isn't a matching value in C. @BENY

Comment: I am just wondering if 3 100 within one group

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, I found that if say group A has amount as [100, -100, 50, 50], then this approach will also see the two 50 as pair, is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: updated to ensure that only - and + pairs per group are matched. regardless of duplicates.